# New Hybrid-HHL algorithm vs VQLS

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm, machine-learning

A team of researchers has realized hybrid quantum algorithm for solving a linear system of equations with exponential speedup that utilizes quantum phase estimation, the algorithm demonstrates quantum supremacy and holds high promise to meet practically relevant challenges.

https://scirate.com/arxiv/2003.12770

https://www.swissquantumhub.com/quantum-supremacy-quantum-hybrid-hhl-algorithm-for-solving-a-system-of-linear-equation/

There is also a variational hybrid quantum-classical algorithm for solving linear systems, with the aim of reducing the circuit depth and doing much of the computation classically, called VQLS.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05820

https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos/tutorial_vqls.html

How can we compare both algorithms?

In the part of the near-term application of H-HHL paper, they talk about Bayesian deep learning application: "One of the promising applications related to deep neural network training was discussed in [1]: since the extension of the Bayesian approach to deep architectures is a serious challenge, one can exploit the hybrid quantum HHL algorithm developed for Gaussian processes in order to calculate a model’s predictor"
[[21](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.11463.pdf)].

Which algorithm should be better in the next-gen state-of-art 53-Qubits quantum computer for the Quantum Bayesian deep learning algorithm?

Comment: I am particularly interested in the comparison of the H-HHL algo with that of the VQLS. I myself am interested in solving large linear systems on NISQ hardware and would like to know which of these I should experiment with.

Answer (score 6):

By a large margin, I would recommend VQLS rather than H-HHL. VQLS is significantly more well-tested, is a more significant leap from the previous state-of-the-art for hybrid quantum/classical linear solvers, and is far more in the ["mainstream"](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/280/2293) realm of quantum computing, meaning that your study will be more relevant in today's quantum computing research climate if you implement VQLS instead of H-HHL.

You could also try both and compare the two!